# Input once for two different variable types in C

Tags: c, variables, pointers, input, casting

I want the user to input a number (`float`) but I want to store the string of characters that where pressed to an array and the actual number to a float at the same time, without asking the user for input twice.

By the way, if you could tell me how to end the program if the string is "e".

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: And maybe you want your shoes polished too, while we are at it?

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work you need to read the sequence of characters into a string, and then parse the string yourself. You can do it either with [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) or with [`atof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/atof.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can read in float variable and later write float value in a string buffer as follows:

```
float f = 0.0f;
char f_buf[100] = "";
scanf("%f", &f);
snprintf(f_buf, 100, "%f", f);  // write float value in a string 
//  Now print both 
printf("f_buf = %s, f = %f", f_buf, f);
```